# Stored procedure vs multiple queries (activerecord)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Just got started with activerecord. I am just wondering if I am making multiple queries in a request, is it better to have a stored procudure? That way, I am making 1 SQL query as oppose to multiple.

For example, a lot of times, I check if a record exists, if not, I create it. That's 2 queries. I can have that in a stored procedure which will make only 1 queries. Is that a way to go to increase performance?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The performance increase will be gained by the fact that the stored procedure will stay compiled and the execution plan will stay stored.  If you make your query from the application, and they are few and far between, that probably won't be the case.

As far as typing goes, it's about the same amount, just in different places.

Comment: Ok but what I am wondering is, is stored procedure something that's done in production in rails? I've never come across it. I always see multiple SQL queries to the db.

Answer (score 0):

> For example, a lot of times, I check if a record exists, if not, I create it. That's 2 queries.

A DBA would probably advise you to

- just insert the row, or
- use the equivalent of the SQL MERGE statement, or
- use whatever other statement your dbms supports (and which I presume ActiveRecord implements in one way or another), like REPLACE, or ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...

and trap the error that results from inserting a duplicate row.

All those should require only one round-trip to the database. And you *have* to trap errors anyway--there are a lot of things that can prevent an INSERT statement from succeeding besides a duplicate key.

On the other hand, if you have a business process that really *requires* a succession of SQL statements, it probably makes sense to write a stored procedure. That's not quite the same thing as "I am making 1 SQL query as oppose to multiple." You still have to execute the succession of SQL statements. You pass less to the server, but that's *probably* not important. The server still executes all the SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I'd bother with this level of performance tuning.

As far as single row inserts, updates, deletes etc are concerned, if you've got the right indexes in place then database performance is likely to be a very small performance concern compared with ruby, DOM processing on the client, network time, etc.. You might save yourself a few milliseconds, but that's unlikely to be significant.

You'll probably appreciate saving time by using:

```
Model.where(:blah => etc).first_or_initialize(:whatever => 'wotsit')
```

... so that you can later fret over a significant performance issue.